# material Design lite - google plus user status

Tags: css, material-design-lite

[image]

When you go to plus.google.com you get this new box where when you click it, it zomes a dialog and you then can add your status, I have the effect working but I can't work out how they got that to look the way it does.

this is my code:

```
<div id="show-dialog" class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--12-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp card-height-small">

         <div class="mdl-section__centre mdl-grid mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
             <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col mdl-cell--top">
               <div class="card__author">
                   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/sports/" alt="user">
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--top">

               <div class="mdl-card__title">

                 <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text">What are you up to?</h1>
                 <div id="tt3" class="icon material-icons">add_a_photo</div>
               </div>
             </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

CSS

```
/*CARDS*/
.mdl-card{width:100%;}
.card-height-small{
  min-height: 95px !important;
  max-height: 95px;
}
.imgcl{
  width:100%;
  height:30vh;
  background: url('http://tfirdaus.github.io/mdl/images/laptop.jpg') center / cover;
}
.mdl-card__media {
    margin: 0;
}
.mdl-card__actions {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  align-items: center;
}
.mdl-card__actions > .mdl-button--icon {
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
.card__author {}

    .card__author img,
    .card__author-content {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .card__author img{
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-right: 0.6em;
    }
```